# save file onclick

Tags: php, html, save

I want to be able to download the csv file on click and not open in the browser

I put this code

```
<a href="file.csv">download file</a>
```

but on click it opens thev file in the browser. In localhost, when I click the link it is being downloaded but when on the server it's opening in the browser

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in order to inform web-browser for opening file-save dialog.

download.php

---

```
  <?php
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv");
    readfile('file.csv');
   ?>
```

showlinks.php

---

```
<a href="download.php">Download file</a>
```

Comment: Of course in *PHP* file. Have a look at *header* - PHP documentation.

Comment: After headers you need to echo the csv - let's say: `echo file_get_contents('file.csv');`

Comment: I use this 
<?php
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
readfile('file.csv');
?>

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 gives you another way - `download` attribute. The problem is currently only Chrome supports it. It will take some time till it will become widely used solution.

So for now I would recommend you @AVD's PHP code.

Comment: And 5 years later(!), this now works in most modern browsers https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try Using following JS Code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:document.execCommand('SaveAs','1','file.csv')>download file</a>
```