# How do I trigger a save as pop-up on clicking of a link? Specifically, how do I trigger than MIME type change?

Tags: php

I've read the following question: [save file onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664402/save-file-onclick)

I understand what it's saying, but I don't understand how I'd make that work for an arbitrary file. Would I set the href attribute equal to a PHP script with that information?

Would it be POST or GET? Can I specify? What method within the script would I use to retrieve the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of the request has little to do with it.  Your request will trigger a response from the server which in turn serves up the file.

It could be a something like `www.site.com/serveFile.php?file=foo.txt`.  Where you are specifying the file to serve up as a GET parameter.

Then in code you could retrieve the file name (or some numeric identifier, or some date range used in retrieving data from the database to serve up CSV content), use that variable, generate content, set the headers.  All there is to it.  Think the post you linked explains the mechanics of serving the content with the correct disposition for a download (save as).

Comment: Ah, thank you. Out of curiosity then, how would I do it with POST, if that is with GET? I can see how that could be done by clicking a link and passing the variable, but with POST, how could you pass it over without a submit button?

Comment: One option would programmatic with JavaScript making an [Xhr post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  Another would be... well using a form with method set to POST.  Using GET vs POST really does not change how you serve the file, just where the submitted data comes in.  Your script could even work with either agnostically just using $_REQUEST, not that I recommend doing that.  Can be a form, an href, a button, all you have to do is make a request to whatever serves the file, optionally passing params.

Comment: Could I have an anchor tag within a form set to post, and somehow when I click it it activates the post request and allows me to identify which was clicked? Is there any disadvantage to using GET? I feel weird about it being accessible by URL for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: Yes.  Possibly.  Anyone can view the source of a page.  Also, I can spoof a POST just as easily as I can spoof a GET.  Both are 'accessible by URL' in any pertinent sense.  You need to read more, look at other code / sites.  Post a new question once you have more info if need be.  To broad a topic.